# Need rxjs expert to solve this blardy conundrum :)

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Really need some help here figuring out this conundrum I'm facing.. I'm gonna paint it in terms of production of donuts. (that circle thing we eat when we're stressed out)

**How it should be**

In an ideal case, user should be able to change Factory & Topping settings of a donut.

The case is, every time a donut is imported, the selected factory will make a donut with selected topping immediately.

The duration of making a donut varies.

After a donut is made, it will be stored.

Now, the problem I am facing is that I am unable to change Factory & Topping. (It is always the default value `N1`, playing with the codes below should help explain the conundrum better.)

> **Note**
>
> Sequence matters.
>   If user keys in `a`,  `b`,  `c`, the donuts should be `["N1a", "N1b", "N1c"]`, even if donut a particular type of donut takes a longer time to make.
>   If user keys in `a`, `2`, `i`, `j`, `k`, `3`, `x`, `y`, the donuts should be `["N1a", "N2i", "N2j", "N2k", "N3x", "N3y"]`

Here's the code I've worked out below, hope you rxjs experts out there find joy in solving this as I've been eating too much donuts trying to solve this already!

**Code:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-uhqftu

```
import {
  fromEvent, combineLatest, of, concat, merge,
} from 'rxjs';
import {
  filter, tap, map, concatMap,
} from 'rxjs/operators';

console.log( 'Press arrow keys to change factory' );
console.log( 'Press [0-9] to change topping' );
console.log( 'Press [a-z] to import donuts' );

const donuts = [];

const allEvents$ = concat( of( 'ArrowUp', '1' ), fromEvent( document, 'keydown' ).pipe( map( event => event.key ) ) );

const factoryLocations = {
  ArrowUp: 'N',
  ArrowLeft: 'W',
  ArrowDown: 'S',
  ArrowRight: 'E',
};

const factoryEvent$ = allEvents$.pipe(
  filter( val => factoryLocations[ val ] ),
  map( val => factoryLocations[ val ] ),
  tap( x => console.log( `%c Change Factory ${ x }`, 'color: #e57373' ) )
);

const toppingEvent$ = allEvents$.pipe(
  filter( val => Number.isInteger( Number( val ) ) ),
  tap( x => console.log( `%c Change Topping ${ x }`, 'color: #f06292' ) )
);

const importDonutEvent$ = allEvents$.pipe(
  filter( val => !Number.isInteger( Number( val ) ) && !factoryLocations[ val ] ),
  tap( x => console.log( `%c Importing Donut ${ x }`, 'color: #f06292' ) )
);

const settingEvents$ = combineLatest( factoryEvent$, toppingEvent$ );

const processEvent$ = settingEvents$.pipe(
  concatMap( ( [ factory, topping ] ) => merge(
    importDonutEvent$
  ).pipe(
    map( type => ( { factory, topping, type } ) ),
  ) )
);

processEvent$.pipe(
  concatMap( ( { factory, topping, type } ) => makeDonut( factory, topping, type ) ),
).subscribe( donut => {
  console.log( `%c DONE   ${ donut }`, 'color: #4db6ac' );
  donuts.push( donut );
  console.log( donuts );
} );

function makeDonut ( factory, topping, type ) {
  const time = Math.random() * 3000;
  const donut = factory + topping + type;

  console.log( `%c MAKING ${ donut }`, 'color: #7986cb' );
  return new Promise( resolve => setTimeout( () => resolve( donut ), time ) );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit late to the party, but the solution is to use `switchMap()` instead of `concatMap()` in `processEvent$`.  Here is the code:

```
const processEvent$ = settingEvents$.pipe(
  switchMap( ( [ factory, topping ] ) => // change to switchMap and delete redundant merge
    importDonutEvent$.pipe(
      map( type => ( { factory, topping, type } ) ),
    )
  )
);
```

And here is a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-pt2efo)

Answer (score 0):

[The other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57664438/853678) is correct. I'd just like to add it's because the `concatMap` waits for the inner observable to complete before it runs its function to produce a new inner observable. In your case `importDonutEvent$` never completes, so the values emitted by `settingEvents$` are queued indefinitely.

Your demo is good, but have you considered using [marble tests](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/testing/marble-testing) to highlight the issue? It's much easier to test and document behaviour. I've created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/jasmine-testing-mya7ai) showing the issue, with two passing implementations and one failing. The second alternative shown is the use of the operator `withLatestFrom`.